# Could anyone please correct my sentences

Tags: grammar

I've written some sentences in English.But,I don't know if they are correct or not grammatically.I would appreciate it , if someone could correct me.
Thank you in advance

1.AS soon as you've seen that massage , please hit the button (the person who might see that massage wants to do something and as you have had experience of doing that , you are telling him what to do )

2.if you've finished with the computer. please turn it off( someone is doing something by your computer and you don't know when is he going to be done )

3.until they haven't eaten they dinner , they won't sleep and we can go to see them (I think ,you will get what i mean )

4.When I was learning English,I wasn't as enthusiastic as he is now .

5.This is exactly what you wanted to happen, this is just as what you what to happen.

6.You got the wall painted just as your wife wanted it to be printed( I mean the way she wanted, happened)

7.If you should see him today , tell him not to call me

Comment: There are at least three "corrected" sentences, in the accepted answer, which are clumsy and not idiomatic. A few are teetering on the border of grammaticality, e,g a native speaker would not say nor write example 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. A**s** soon as **you see** that **message**, please hit the button
2. **I**f you've finished with the computer, please turn it off
3. **U**ntil they'**ve** eaten **their** dinner they won't **be able to** sleep and we can go see them
4. I wasn't as enthusiastic as he is now **when I was learning English**
5. This is exactly what you wanted to happen, **just the way you wanted**
6. You got the wall painted just **the way** wife wanted it to be
7. If you should see him today, tell him not to call me *(no change needed)*

EDIT: When writing a comma, make sure there's a space between the comma and the next word. Conversely, the letter preceding the comma shouldn't have a space. **Word, word** is correct, **word,word** isn't, and neither is **word , word**. Also make sure you always capitalize the *first letter* of the *first word* on every sentence.

Comment: You can't be sure the OP meant _message_ instead of _massage_. ;)

Answer (score 1):

> 1. As soon as you see that message, please press the button.

I have used 'press' the button instead of 'hitting' the button, I think we do not use the term hit the button formally and also you can use 'that/this' for referring to message when you actually mention the message with the context for this we can simply say.

> 1. Please press the button, as soon as you see the message.

similarly, being specific regarding the task not just 'finished'

> 2. If you'v finished your work with the computer, then please turn it off.

'eaten dinner' sound not cool to me, I am changing the sentence structure but i think it is conveying the message and according to me 'have their dinner' is self sufficient..

> 3. They will not sleep, until they have their dinner. Till that time we can go to see them.
> 4. I wasn't as enthusiastic as he is now when I was learning English.
> 5. This is exactly what you wanted to happen, just the way you wanted it to happen.
> 6. You got the wall painted just the way your wife wanted.

or

> 6. You get the wall painted just the way your wife has wanted.
> 7. If you should see him today, tell him not to call me (no change needed)

Comment: In addition to _press_ the button, we might also _push_ the button.